# Python superclass __init__ method not called

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run the following program in Python 3.6:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

def startElementHandler(name, attributes):
    print("Name:", name)

class Parser(xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser):
    def __init__(self, html=0, target=None, encoding=None):
        super(Parser, self).__init__(html, target, encoding)
        self.parser.StartElementHandler = startElementHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = Parser()
    print("Success")
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\src\python\base_init\base_init.py", line 12, in <module>
    parser = Parser()
  File "D:\src\python\base_init\base_init.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.parser.StartElementHandler = startElementHandler
AttributeError: 'Parser' object has no attribute 'parser'
```

As you can see from the [`XMLParser` class source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#l1446) I'm calling its `__init__()` method with the correct arguments and `XMLParser`'s `parser` attribute is set within it.

What is happening is that the `XMLParser.__init__()` method doesn't get called. What am I doing wrong? It must be something silly, but I just can't see it.

Comment: Your error message visibly doesn't match the code you posted. The code you posted should be fine.

Comment: Yet that is what I get when running the above program under Python 3.6.0 on Windows.

Comment: Are you sure? The code you posted says `self.parser`, but the error message says `super(Parser, self).parser`. That error message isn't coming from that code.

Comment: You are right, I copied the error message from a previous attempt. I corrected my question.

Comment: I believe the C accelerator for `XMLParser` *doesn't* have these attributes set. This seems like an odd discrepancy.

Comment: I believe your right. The C struct definition does have a `parser` member, but it isn't a `PyObject`. If you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C accelerator [that's imported](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3dc7c52a9f4fb83be3e26e31e2c7cd9dc1cb41a2/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L1646) for `XMLParser` doesn't have the `parser` attribute set. A somewhat viable option is to disable it's importing by setting it's value as `None` in `sys.modules`:

```
import sys
sys.modules['_elementtree'] = None
```

Of course, in order for this to work, it needs to be done *before* any imports of `ElementTree` occur and, obviously, you'll get a performance hit.

As for *why* this is, I'm guessing the `parser` attribute is considered part of the private API for `XMLParser`, no documentation for it exists (and it doesn't look like an omission). As such, it should not be relied upon.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion. If the performance hit isn't too bad it may be viable. Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "these attributes," and add a bit more detail to explain how this relates to the question being asked.  I'm trying to follow this as a third party and it's not clear

Comment: There's a couple of attributes set by the Pure Python implementation of `XMLParser` (the `parser` attribute included) that aren't set for the C one @SamHartman. Because the C implementation is imported at the end of `ElementTree.py` in order to provide a performance boost, it masks the Python implementation and results in the error OP is seeing.

Answer (score 0):

For python 2.X your code is fine but for python 3.x you will have to change this

`self.parser.StartElementHandler = startElementHandler` to `self.StartElementHandler = startElementHandler`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

def startElementHandler(name, attributes):
    print("Name:", name)

class Parser(xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser):
    def __init__(self, html=0, target=None, encoding=None):
        super(Parser, self).__init__(html, target, encoding)
        self.StartElementHandler = startElementHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = Parser()
    print("Success")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print starting element's tag name, you can use [`xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) which does not require patching the parser object.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

for event, elem in xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse(filepath, events=['start']):
    print('Name:', elem.tag)
```

- filepath can be a xml file path or a file-like object.

Comment: Mine is a stripped down example. I'm trying to access the `parser` attribute in order to intercept CDATA sections to circumvent their stripping away by ElementTree.